# Excel VBA Cannot fix the Runtime error ' 9': Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I am a newbie of excel VBA.
Below is my code. It always throw runtime error. I have tried to fix it with my all effort.
Can anyone save my life?
I appreciate any response.

```
Function GetUniqueAndCount()

          Dim sheet As Worksheet
          Set sheet = ActiveSheet
          Dim index As Integer
          Dim componentList() As String
          Dim typeList() As String
          Dim temp() As String
          Dim arraySize As Integer
          Dim row As Integer
          Dim iVal As Integer
          Dim horizontal, vertical, borderString As String

          row = 1

          Do Until Application.CountA(sheet.Rows(row)) = 0


              temp = Filter(typeList, Cells(row, 3))
              On Error GoTo EMPTY_ARRAY:
              If (UBound(temp) = -1 And Cells(row, 3) <> vbstringnull) Then
                  ReDim Preserve componentList(index)
                  ReDim Preserve typeList(index)
                  componentList(index) = Cells(row, 2)
                  typeList(index) = Cells(row, 3)
                  arraySize = arraySize + 1
                  index = index + 1
              End If

EMPTY_ARRAY:

Erase temp()

row = row + 1

Loop

End function
```

Comment: do you really want to use test and typeList as array? what is the purpose of 'Filter' in your code.

Comment: which line is showing error? And what are you trying to get using this code?

Comment: `Filter` is the builtin array matching function.

Comment: FYI it's `vbnullstring` and not `vbstringnull`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`temp = Filter(typeList, Cells(row, 3))`

`typeList` is an uninitialized array in the first iteration, if you pass such an array to `filter()` no array is returned so `temp` remains uninitialized so `UBound(temp)` is illegal.

Once `typeList` has been redimmed you would get back `-1` as you expect.

Test that you have assigned to `typeList` before attempting to use it as a source for `filter()`

Also remove the `On Error` and fix whatever causes that condition if its not the above.